# Do statement under a where clause

Tags: haskell, scope, functional-programming, monads, do-notation

I'm trying to convert *`IO [String]`* to `[String]` with *`<-`* binding; however, I need to use a `do` block to do that under a `where` statement, but Haskell complains about the indentation all the time. Here is the code:

```
decompEventBlocks :: IO [String] -> IO [[String]]
decompEventBlocks words
 | words' /= [] = block : (decompEventBlocks . drop $ (length block) words')
 | otherwise = []
  where 
   do
    words' <- words
    let block = (takeWhile (/="END") words')
```

What is the reason for that ? And how can we use *`do`* block in a *`where`* statement ? Moreover, is there any chance that we can have some statements before the guards ?

Comment: `do`-blocks are not statements, they are values. What do you think this is supposed to do? Like I said in your last question, *please* study monads before using them!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have used to that kind of words. What I meant is that I want to declare a new value of type [String] from the value of type IO [String].

Comment: @AJFarmar I'm just somehow trying to comply that last 2 line of code in the definition of the function, that is it.

Comment: to deal with indentation, you can use `do { x ; y ; z }` explicit syntax.

Comment: Change your function to be `[String] -> [[String]]` and then just use `fmap` to lift it into the `IO` monad.

Comment: @AJFarmar Before learning the inner workings of the language, I would like to knock my head againts the constraints of the language a bit. Without it, there is a little motivation to learn.

Comment: you can't use a variable bound in your do block (i.e. `words'`) outside the do block (i.e. in a guard). you will have to restructure your code.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Monads are not *'the inner workings of the language'*, they are a vital feature of Haskell that *defines* its I/O constraints. Without an understanding of monads, you will not be able to write good Haskell. Learn about monads!

Comment: @AJFarmar while true, a do notation can be mastered on its own, as a DSL in its own right, with few rules to follow. this could be a first, smaller step to master. (also, including all the optional parens, braces and semicolons everywhere (do, case, $, ...) can really help a beginner by removing any additional uncertainty with the syntax they might still have).

Comment: @AJFarmar The reason why I haven't learned monads is that I'm math student, and I would first like to learn Category theory, and then come back and learn monads etc.

Comment: @onurcanbektas I'm also a math student, and I learned monads way before I began. Trust me, you're not losing out. If you're continuing to use Haskell, learn monads.

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember: `do`-blocks are [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for monadic notation. This means the following applies:

```
do {a; b} = a >> b
dp {a <- b; c} = b >>= \a -> c
```

In other words, when using `do`-notation, you are actually producing values. This is why you can't just have a `do`-block in the top level of your `where` statement.

The way to solve this is to put the function into a `do`-block:

```
decompEventBlocks :: IO [String] -> IO [[String]]
decompEventBlocks words = do
    -- We unwrap the IO [String], but we keep it in the do-block,
    -- because it must be kept in a monadic context!
    words' <- words 
    let block = (takeWhile (/="END") words')
    -- This is equivalent to the guards you had in your function.
    -- NB return :: Monad m => a -> m a, to keep it in a monadic context!
    if not $ null words'
        then do 
          -- Since the recursion is monadic, we must bind it too:
          rest <- decompEventBlocks $ return $ drop (length block) words'
          return $ block : rest
        else return []
```

To learn about monads, `do`-notation, `>>=`, and `>>`, I highly reccommend reading [the LYAH chapters](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#getting-our-feet-wet-with-maybe) to gain a good understanding before attempting more monadic code.

Comment: I just directly copy-paste the code, but it throws 2 errors becuase in (_:_) it is expected [String], and not IO [String]; this is at least what ghci says.

Comment: Ah, this is a flaw due to the original definition, updating now. (Updated now)

Comment: But still the argument of _decompEventBlocks_ in rest <- ... is [String ]?

Comment: By the way, the code is giving error (which is the reason for the my question above.)

Comment: @onurcanbektas I get no error when running this code verbatim. If you're getting an error, find the code causing it and post another question elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. (PS: I have decided to get rid of IO's and edit my orijinal code with the style of your code.)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot *convert* for IO String to a String.

What you can do, however, is bind the contents of IO String to a 'variable', but that will still result in the whole computation being embedded inside IO.

```
foo = do
   x <- baz -- here baz is the IO String
   let x' = doStuff x
   return x' -- embeds the String inside IO, as otherwise the computation would result in IO ()
```

To answer your question

```
foo x = baz x -- x here is your 'IO String'
  where
    baz x = do
      x' <- x
      return $ doStuff x'
```

Answer (score 0):

As a slightly different angle on AJFarmar's answer: The only things you can have in a `where` are declarations. `do` blocks aren't declarations, they are expressions. I.e. this is the same as if you tried to write `where 2+5`. If you want to declare `block` in a `where`, it *must* be

```
where
  // can have other declarations, even mutually recursive
  block = ...
```

Comment: So, `words' <- words` is not a declaration ? but why ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas Becase `words' <- words; b` is syntactic sugar for `words >>= \words' -> b`. I explained this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Do* notation is used to write expressions of the general form

```
ex :: Monad m => m t
let ex = do 
          {  x <- foo         -- foo        :: Monad m => m a,   x :: a
          ;  y <- bar x       -- bar  x     :: Monad m => m b,   y :: b
          ;  z <- baz x y     -- baz  x y   :: Monad m => m c,   z :: c
          ;  quux x y z       -- quux x y z :: Monad m => m t
          }
```

Notice all the `m`s are the same, and `a`, `b`, `c`, ... can be different, though the `t` in the last *do* sub-expression's type and the overall *do* expression's type is the same.

The *do* notation variables are said to be "bound" by the `<-` construct. They come into scope at their introduction (to the left of `<-`) and remain in scope for all the subsequent *do* sub-expressions.

One built-in monadic expression available for any monad is `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`. Thus `x <- return v` *binds* `x` to `v`, so that `x` will be available in the subsequent sub-expressions, and will have the value of `v`.

All the *do* variables are *confined* to that *`do`* block, and *can not* be used outside it. Each variable's scope is all the code in the same `do` block, below / after the variable's binding.

This also means that `<-`'s is a non-recursive binding, since the variable can't go on its right hand side as well as the left: it will be two *different* variables with the same name, in that case, and the variable on the right will have to have been established somewhere above that point.

There are a few general patterns here:

```
do { _ <- p ; _ <- q ; r }    ===   do { p ; q ; r }
do { x <- p ; return x }      ===   do { p }          ===   p
do { x <- return v ; foo x }  ===   do { foo v }      ===   foo v
do { p ; q ; r }              ===   do { p ; do { q ; r } }
                              ===   do { do { p ; q } ; r }
do { x <- p ;                 ===   do { x <- p ;
     y <- q x ;                          z <- do { y <- q x ;
     return (foo x y) }                            return (foo x y) } ;
                                         return z }
```

All the `Monad m => m a` expressions are just that, expressions, and so can in particular be an `if - then - else` expressions with both the consequent and the alternative branches being of the same monadic type (which is often confusing for beginners):

```
    do { x <- p ;
         y <- if (pred x) then (foo x) else (bar x) ;
         return (baz x y) }
```

*update:* One of the main points of the monad is its total separation of effects from the pure calculations. Once *in* a monad, you can't *"get out"*. Monadic computations can use pure calculations, but not vice versa.