# Why can't I put a print function statement here?

Tags: haskell, boolean, monads, io-monad, do-notation

I am trying following code with try-catch block:

```
import System.Environment  
import System.IO  
import System.IO.Error  
import Control.Exception

isBinary :: String -> Bool
isBinary ss = do 
    print "In isBinary fn"   -- works if this line is removed.
    let ans = any (\c -> ord c > 127) ss
    ans

toTry :: String -> IO ()  
toTry firline = do
        print "In toTry fn."
        let answer = isBinary firline
        if not answer then do
            print "Sent line not binary: "
        else
            print "Sent line binary"

handler :: IOError -> IO ()  
handler e = putStrLn "Whoops, had some trouble!"  

ss = "this is a test"
main = do 
    toTry ss `catch` handler
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
$ runghc trycatch3.hs 

trycatch3.hs:9:9: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘IO Bool’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: print "in isBinary fn"
      In the expression:
        do { print "in isBinary fn";
             let ans = any (\ c -> ...) ss;
             return ans }
      In an equation for ‘isBinary’:
          isBinary ss
            = do { print "in isBinary fn";
                   let ans = ...;
                   return ans }

trycatch3.hs:10:30: error:
    • Variable not in scope: ord :: Char -> Integer
    • Perhaps you meant one of these:
        ‘or’ (imported from Prelude), ‘odd’ (imported from Prelude)
```

The error goes away and program works well if the print statement is removed from isBinary function.

Why can't I put print statement in this function?

Comment: Do you understand what "pure" means in the statement "Haskell is a pure functional language"?

Comment: I have read/heard about it but do not understand it fully.

Comment: `do` notation always gets you some type of `IO` value (e.g. `IO Bool`, in this case), so this is pretty straightforward.

Comment: In short, Haskell has no *statements*.

Comment: What is disadvantage of simple statements? Why are they being avoided here so much?

Comment: by "statement" in functional programming vernacular is meant something that has no value, and is used for its effect. it is popular to say that "functional" are "expression-oriented" languages where *expressions* are *evaluated* for their value. so in Scheme for example, instead of having an explicit `return` *statement* like they have in C, simply the last evaluated expression's value is returned as the overall expression's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is, "because *types*". Specifically:

```
isBinary :: String -> Bool
isBinary ss = do 
  ....
```

Since it's a `do` block, the return type of `isBinary` *must* match a monadic type `Monad m => m t` for some `m` and some `t`. Here, since `print "" :: IO ()`, `m` is `IO`, so it should've been

```
isBinary :: String -> IO Bool
isBinary ss = do
```

and now

```
    print "In isBinary fn"                 -- works
    let ans = any (\c -> ord c > 127) ss   -- also works
    ans                                    -- doesn't work
```

`ans` doesn't work because of types, again. Its type is `Bool`, but it must be `IO Bool` -- first, because this `do` block belongs to `IO` monad, on account of `print`; and second, because of the return type of the function as a whole.

Instead, use

```
    return ans
```

and now it'll work, because `return` injects a value into the monadic context, and being the last `do` block value it becomes the value produced by the `do` block overall (if `return val` appears in the middle it just passes the `val` to the next step in the combined computation).

The function `toTry` will have to be augmented to use the new definition:

```
toTry :: String -> IO ()  
toTry firline = do
        print "In toTry fn."
        -- let answer = isBinary firline    -- incorrect, now!
        answer <- isBinary firline          -- isBinary ... :: IO Bool
        if not answer then do               --       answer ::    Bool
            print "Sent line not binary: "
        else
            print "Sent line binary"
```

`m a` on the right of `<-`, `a` on the left.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50815136/849891) for a general description of `do` notation.

Comment: Great answer, I would also add a short explanation about `return` in haskell vs. its meaning in other languages as this causes confusion to many learners.

Comment: @m-aroosi thanks for the edit! I would often notice this error in posts of others, and here I made it myself. the irony!

Answer (score 2):

You might be confused by the same print line working in `toTry`, but not in `isBinary`. The difference stems from the declaration:

```
isBinary :: String -> Bool
```

This means that `isBinary` is a pure function (i.e. no side effects), taking a string and returning a boolean. In fact, you could simplify it to

```
isBinary ss = any (\c -> ord c > 127) ss
```

or even use the point-free style

```
isBinary = any (\c -> ord c > 127)
```

However, `toTry` is

```
toTry :: String -> IO ()
```

I.e. it takes a string and returns the `IO` monad which is impure (can have side effects, such as printing text to the console).

Haskell is a language that encourages using pure functions, and enforces it using the type system, by forcing the programmer to explicitly mark impure code.

Further reading:
[What does "pure" mean in "pure functional language"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382223/what-does-pure-mean-in-pure-functional-language)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, it seems your use of `print` in `isBinary` is not an integral part of what you want the function to do, but merely a debug print statement that will be removed later on. In that case, you do not want to change the type of `isBinary` to `String -> IO Bool` (for more on that, see [Will Ness' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56221543/2751851)), as you don't actually need `IO` except for debugging. Rather, the core libraries offer [the `Debug.Trace` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html), which caters to this kind of situation. With it, we can add your debug print statement like this:

```
isBinary :: String -> Bool
isBinary ss = trace "In isBinary fn" $ any (\c -> ord c > 127) ss
```

Then, once you are done debugging, you can remove the use of `trace` -- and it bears repeating you really should do that later on. Quoting the `Debug.Trace` documentation:

> Functions for tracing and monitoring execution.
>
> These can be useful for investigating bugs or performance problems. They should *not* be used in production code.